# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while counting ASCII character frequency

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, ascii, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to count the frequency of ASCII characters from a String input that was converted to a character array.

I tried to implement the accepted answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539476/counting-character-occurrences-in-a-string-frequency) thread, along with my code to print the results in a 3-column table.

```
package com.mypackage.mp;

import java.util.*;

public class AsciiCounter {

    public static void displayAsciiOccurrence(String inputWords) {
        int[] iaCount = new int[256]; //this
        char[] caInputWords = inputWords.toCharArray();

        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < caInputWords.length; i++) {
            iaCount[caInputWords[i]]++;
        }

        // Print table
        System.out.println("\nDEC\tASCII\tFREQ");

        for(int ctr = 0; ctr < 256; ctr++) {
            System.out.println(ctr +"\t" + (char) (ctr) + "\t" + iaCount[caInputWords[i]]); //this
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputWords = null;
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter words: ");
        inputWords = scn.nextLine();

        displayAsciiOccurrence(inputWords); //this

        scn.close();
    }
}
```

However, it is returning an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. My desired output is supposed to be:

```
Enter words: AA bC! d

DEC     ASCII       FREQ
0
..      ..          ..
32                  2
33      !           1
..      ..          ..
65      A           2
66      B           0
67      C           1
..
98      b           1
99      c           0
100     d           1
..
255
```

(The `..` pertains to whatever is in between and must print 0 as frequency.)

**Stack Trace:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
>     at
>   com.mypackage.mp.AsciiCounter.displayAsciiOccurrence(AsciiCounter.java:20)
>     at
>   com.mypackage.mp.AsciiCounter.main(AsciiCounter.java:31)

Comment: Can you add at what line you get that exception? Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the full stack trace please?

Comment: Note that `.toCharArray()` will essentially "duplicate" all characters in the string; you may want to use `String`'s `.charAt()` instead.

Comment: Edited question to include stack trace. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the i variable has not been reset. but you don't need to use variable i at all after the frequency calculation. You need to use ctr for frequency of all the characters.

```
    for(int ctr = 0; ctr < 256; ctr++) {
        System.out.println(ctr +"\t" + (char) (ctr) + "\t" + iaCount[ctr]);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I have also used iaCount.length instead of hard coding 256. Marked as accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

The error is in your printing loop:

```
System.out.println(ctr +"\t" + (char) (ctr) + "\t" + iaCount[caInputWords[i]]);
```

Since `i` hasn't changed since the first loop, it is equal to `caInputWords.length` at this point.

I guess you just meant:

```
System.out.println(ctr +"\t" + (char) (ctr) + "\t" + iaCount[ctr]);
```

As a side note, you might not want to print all the ASCII characters themselves. Some of them don't represent printable characters or are whitespace. One simple way around this is to check that `iaCount[ctr] > 0` before printing so you only print characters that were in the String to begin with.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The machine problem requires it prints the entire ASCII table including non-printable characters and whitespace. Should the requirements need it, your tip would be useful. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem in your second loop:

```
    for(int ctr = 0; ctr < 256; ctr++) {
        System.out.println(ctr +"\t" + (char) (ctr) + "\t" 
            + iaCount[caInputWords[i]] // HERE
        );
    }
```

You meant `iaCount[ctr]`! You use `i` which is 256 when you enter this loop, since it has been set to this value by your previous loop. And since the `iaCount` array is only 256 chars long, this index is out of bounds.

Also, you fail to check what happens if you enter a non ASCII character.

To avoid this kind of error, change your first `for` loop to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
```

Doing so in your first loop would have shown that `i` didn't exist in the second.

Answer (score 1):

That line can throw exception.

`System.out.println(ctr +"\t" + (char) (ctr) + "\t" + iaCount[caInputWords[i]]);`
Change it to that

```
 for(int ctr = 0; ctr < 256; ctr++) {
            System.out.println(ctr +"\t" + (char) (ctr) + "\t" + iaCount[ctr]);
        }
```